# COUNTIF with a positive and negative criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I need to count the number of cells in which the cells in "LIST A" appear in the set of values contained in column D **AND** the cells in "LIST B" do not appear in column E.

I am trying to use something like the following array formula, but so far have had limited success:

```
={SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A21,D2:D5,B2:B21,"<>"&E2:E3))}
```

Please note that the data contained in this example is different to the data in my real table. The real table is considerably longer and more complex than this table.

Any suggestions?

[image: Example]

Comment: In situations like this, it's best to "show your working", and use a couple of extra columns for intermediate columns. I dislike elaborate COUNTIFS with a vengence.

Comment: countif uses "OR" which means: count each value in B2:B21 which is at least one time not ANY of E2:E4 (this counts for all numbers... but you can use this nonarray formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(D2:D5,A2:A21)*(COUNTIF(E2:E5,B2:B21)-1))*-1`

Comment: Dirk Reichel, this formula works well - but I don't quite understand why. Secondly if, for example, in column C there were a third list with "TRUE or FALSE" values, and the cell had to be 'TRUE' - can this fit in to your suggestion?

Comment: sure... while this formula may be more understandable for you: `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(D2:D5,A2:A21)*NOT(COUNTIF(E2:E5,B2:B21)))`... a third column can be added as the rules need to be set... i'll write an answer to show how

Comment: Sorry, that is a mistake by me - I have corrected it now. Thanks for noticing

Comment: Ah! You've changed the second criteria range to just E2:E3, no? Wasn't it E2:E4 previously?

Comment: Yes it was previously - I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just for your example the formula like in my comment will be enough

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(D2:D5,A2:A21)*NOT(COUNTIF(E2:E5,B2:B21)))
```

the problem ocures if you have multiple values you want to exclude. then you need to use a negative countif(s)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*NOT(COUNTIF(E2:E5,B2:B21)))
```

this would count all lines which contain anything of the exclude list. But the `NOT` inside the sumproduct will switch it to opposite (the 1* is needed cus it would only contain bool which can't be count)

if you have column C with bool (true/false or 1/0) you can simply add that:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(D2:D5,A2:A21)*NOT(COUNTIF(E2:E5,B2:B21))*C2:C21)
```

or also `(C2:C21>12)` if that is what you need... but you also could include it to the include list (if A is A/B/E/F and C is (2/4/6)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(D2:D5,A2:A21,F2:F5,C2:C21)*NOT(COUNTIF(E2:E5,B2:B21)))
```

But every exclude needs its own countif (B is not X/Y and C is not 8/9/11)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(D2:D5,A2:A21)*NOT(COUNTIF(E2:E5,B2:B21))*NOT(COUNTIF(F2:F5,C2:C21))
```

As already said: Having formulas which return `""` may return false counts (keep that in mind)

Comment: Be aware that your formula may fail if both of the following are true: 1) One or more of the ranges passed as COUNTIF's range parameter include empty cells and 2) Empty cells are possible within the ranges passed as the criteria parameter, whereas the MATCH set-up I posted is unaffected by such cases. 1) appears to be true, since the OP is including empty cells in the range E2:E4 (E4 is - currently at least - empty), so, although there are no empty cells within the range B2:B21 at the moment (so that 2) is currently false), if this changes then your formula will fail.

Comment: i've run several tests and got no errors... can you show me an example for me to get the error? if i include empty cells they wont be count if in column A and empty cells in column B count as not to exclude... missing both will not count it... i really don't get it :(

Comment: Apologies. I should've clarified that it fails with null strings, not "genuinely" empty cells. So, for example, with E3 and E4 blank, as in the OP's original example, make it so that some of the cells within the range B2:B21 return a null string "".

Comment: ya that is true `=""` will raise errors... (as it does so many times) i will include that to my answer

Comment: Indeed. Pesky little things! Actually my set-up will fail if such strings are possible within the range D2:E5 (though not in A2:B21). I had no basis on which to assume that those in D2:E5 were "genuine" blanks, yet those in A2:B21 potentially null strings.

Comment: but your problem can be covered up with a simple `IF(LEN(E2:E5),...` while i don't know if `ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B21,IF(LEN(E2:E5),E2:E5),0))` will work that way... (still the list should not include any `FALSE` then... hmm... running in circles :P

Comment: @DirkReichel, the final example isn't working for me. I'm currently trying out `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(D2:D5,A2:A21)*COUNTIF(F2,C2:C21)*NOT(COUNTIF(E2:E5,B2:B21)))` where my `F2` is testing for a word (e.g. "TRUE") and column C contains a list of words.

Comment: You want the first list and the third list but not the second one... or do you want A or C? So if only A or C matchs up (and B does not exclude it) do you want to count it?

Comment: A and C to both match (D and F respectively) and B does not exclude it (i.e. not excluded in E). If easier, I'm happy to ask as a separate question or update this question.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(D2:D5,A2:A21)*NOT(COUNTIF(E2:E5,B2:B21))*(C2:C21=F2))` should do it...

Answer (score 1):

Best to switch to `SUMPRODUCT` in such cases:

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A21,D2:D5,0)),1-ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B21,E2:E5,0)))`

Regards